# How to get output line by line using xlsWriterr

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I am simply printing line by line list from the loop and my output is something like this:

```
['    4.0\n', '   17.2\n', '    7.0\n']   
['    0.0\n']
['    4.0\n', '   16.7\n', '    4.0\n']
['    4.0\n', '   16.7\n', '    4.0\n']
['    4.0\n', '   16.7\n', '    4.0\n']
['    4.0\n', '   16.7\n', '    4.0\n']
['    4.0\n', '   16.4\n', '    4.0\n']
```

## But in my excel output im just only getting the first line something like this:

[image]

## My expected result is these:

[image]

My current Code is here:

```
count = 0   
DataList = []                                               
for line, file in enumerate(PM2Line):       
    if POA in file: 
        DataList.append(file[32:50])                                
print DataList #--> this will print the list of output      
worksheet.write_column('A1', DataList) #--> My problem is just getting first line.  
workbook.close()
```

Any suggestion or comments.

Comment: What are you expecting as output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you are overwriting the column with new values in each iteration. Your code should be looking something like -

```
#some loop
    count = 0   
    DataList = []                                               
    for line, file in enumerate(PM2Line):       
        if POA in file: 
            DataList.append(file[32:50])                                
    print DataList #--> this will print the list of output      
    worksheet.write_column('A1', DataList) #--> My problem is just getting first line.  
    workbook.close()
```

You should keep the `DataList` outside the outer loop and only update the worksheet outside that loop. Example -

```
#open worksheet here instead of inside the loop.
DataList = []
#some loop
    count = 0                                              
    for line, file in enumerate(PM2Line):       
        if POA in file: 
            DataList.append(file[32:50])                                
    print DataList     
worksheet.write_column('A1', DataList)
workbook.close()
```

Comment: I think It become worse, because it also printing single line and splitted into multiple lines.

Comment: Try the latest - `worksheet.write_column('A1', map(str.strip, chain.from_iterable(DataList))) `

Comment: got same output, do I need to shift to other way? or there is a better way to get this.

Comment: Can you show exact output you are getting right now?

Comment: Instead of above change (same code as your previous code) , what happens if you do `DataList.extend()` instead of `append` when creating it?

Comment: Yes, I already tried to use extend, but its weird because I am also getting the same output from the append.

Comment: @Rockn'Roll And what exactly does -` print DataList` - print for you? is it a list of list of strings? or list of strings?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92002/discussion-between-rock-n-roll-and-anand-s-kumar).